# Design Issue - Html Mobile

Tags: html, select

I am designing a website for desktops and mobiles. I do not have a mobile to test this on.

I have a `<select>` and am going to put a lot of `<option>`s in it. Maybe 40ish to 70ish. Is this good practice for mobiles? Will some of the options be hidden offscreen? Is there anything I can do to limit problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en) in Chrome to emulate a mobile device to a certain extent.

Comment: This looks great, but I cannot seem to get the Chrome to recognise any of my screen taps to open a select, or even press a button. Is there something I am doing fundamentally wrong?